# webapi: schedule action at certain time

Tags: c#, timer, asp.net-web-api2

In my webapi application, I want to schedule an action at certain time. Here is my code:

```
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Timer> timers;

        public void Schedule(TimeSpan when, Action<ElapsedEventArgs, Item> expiredCallback, Item item)
        {
            Timer timer = null;

            if (timers.TryGetValue(item.Label, out timer))
            {
                return;
            }

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = when.TotalMilliseconds;
            var addResult = this.timers.TryAdd(item.Label, timer);
            if (addResult)
            {
                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => 
                {
                    Timer expiredTimer = null;

                    if (this.timers.TryRemove(item.Label, out expiredTimer))
                    {
                        expiredTimer.Enabled = false;
                        expiredTimer.Dispose();
                    }

                    expiredCallback(e, item);
                };

                timer.Start();
            }

        }
```

The problem with this code is that if the application pool recycles after I schedule an action, I am assuming that the action will not be executed, since the timers are held in memory.

A better solution is to schedule a task using a scheduler api and from that scheduled task to call the api, but this would complicate things... So is there a simple way to make this code work in the scenario that I've described?

Comment: I think [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) should be good enough for this scenarios. Why don't use it?

Comment: You can use Hangfire where you can setup server storage as your database. So, all scheduling metadata would be stored in database and  application pool recycles don't affect it

Comment: Thirding the suggestion of using a real scheduling framework for this.

Comment: so if I would start using quartz or hangfire, I will also need a database for these schedulers, right?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres, have pgAgent to control shedules. It is a free easy_to_use time sheduler, where you may shedule all tasks that needs to be run. All the tasks are saved in tables, so nothing is lost if the webserver restarts. And it logs in the tablelog, if a shedule fails.

Example picks of the pgagent (my local server).

[image]

[image]